# multipart upload to s3 using ng-file-upload

Tags: amazon-s3, ng-file-upload

Can somebody point me to an example of doing multipart upload using ng-file-upload. Also if the upload can be paused/resumed (like when the internet goes down or user puts the machine to sleep).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I switched to evaporate.js for multipart upload.